# Adding Multiple Countdown Timers to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My goal is to have a unique (hh:mm:ss) countdown `timer` for each populated `uicollectionviewcell` within a `uicollectionview`.

Below is the (abbreviated) code I've been able to compile, but am stuck on getting it to really work in any capacity...any guidance would be appreciated.

```
class VC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var timer = Timer()
var secondsRemaining: Int?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ExampleCollectionViewCell    

    let expirationDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 24, to: startDate)
    secondsRemaining = expirationDate?.seconds(from: startDate)

    timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(countdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    return cell
}

    @objc func countdown() {
    secondsRemaining = secondsRemaining! - 1
    if secondsRemaining == 0 {
        print("CELL TIME HAS EXPIRED!")
        timer.invalidate()
    } else {
        let hours = secondsRemaining! / 3600
        let minutes = (secondsRemaining! % 3600) / 60
        let seconds = (secondsRemaining! % 3600) % 60
        let countdownLabelString = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)

        //i need to take this countdownLabelString and set it to the 
        //countdownLabel.text that is an element of each cell. i tried 
        //doing all of this in the cell subclass, but no luck... 
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head - since `UICollectionView` uses dynamic cells (prototypes) - each cell is simply a "template" for what you want to display.  This would suggest that each time the collection view requests a cell, it needs to be backed by some kind of data, which can be used to populate the cell. This suggestions that, at the very least, you will need a list of "times", including the "start time" and "duration", one for each cell, then each cell just needs to use this information to calculate the duration - then you just either need to refresh all the collection view or individual cells

Comment: I'd also consider using a [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999022/how-to-format-time-intervals-for-user-display-social-network-like-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to format the duration

Comment: You should never rely on a timer to measure a time interval. Save the date it starts or even better  just add the desired duration to the start date (now) and use it as the expiration date. Btw you can create a custom object subclassing UILabel and add the timer to the it instead of the view controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collection view cells are not made to update constantly. If you want them to update, you have to tell them to update.

If you want each cell to show a different amount of time remaining, you need a data model that saves a separate `expirationDate` for each indexPath you display. If your collection view is a simple one-dimensional list of items, like a table view, then you could just use a 1-dimensional array. If your collection view shows a grid of cells you might need a 2 dimensional array of model objects.

Each time you add an item to your data model, include an `expirationDate` value. (The `Date` when that item expires.)

Then have your timer call the collection view's `reloadData` method each time it fires.

In your `collectionView(collectionView:cellForItemAt:)` method, use the indexPath to figure out which item in your data model you are displaying. Look up the `expirationDate` for that indexPath, calculate the time remaining from now until your expiration date, and display that information in the cell. (Use the `Calendar` method `dateComponents(_:from:to:)` to calculate the number of hours, minutes, and seconds between now and your expiration date.)

### EDIT

**DO NOT** decrement a counter every time your timer fires. Do math on the difference between your expiration date and the current date using `dateComponents(_:from:to:)`

### EDIT #2:

A sample collection view controller that does something like what you want is below:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "aCell"

class DatesCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController {

    weak var timer: Timer?
    var dates: [Date] = []
    lazy var componentsFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        return formatter
    }()

        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for _ in 1...100 {
            let interval = Double(arc4random_uniform( 10000)) + 120
            dates.append(Date().addingTimeInterval(interval))
        }

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dates.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        
        let now = Date()
        let expireDate = dates[indexPath.row]
        guard  expireDate > now else {
            cell.intervalLabel.text = "00"
            return cell
        }
        
        let desiredComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(desiredComponents, from: now, to: expireDate)
        cell.intervalLabel.text = self.componentsFormatter.string(from: components)

        return cell
    }
}
```

The code above looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks, i did not try this exact implementation as i think i solved it prior to your latest edit, but the initial comment did jog my memory to create a dataSource for the expiration times for each individual cell. i do have another related issue (https://stackoverflow.com/q/50037443/9466631), not sure if you're able to help out here!

Comment: If my answer enabled you to solve your problem then you should accept it.

Comment: I suggest replacing `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` with reloading just the visible cells.

Comment: @rmaddy since this application needs to update **all** visible cells every time the timer fires, isn't `reloadData()` appropriate here? `reloadData()` doesn't load cells that are not visible. (it calculates which cells are visible and only calls `cellForItemAt` on those cells.) Granted, the collection view has to do layout calculations, but my thought was that for the user code, simpler was better.