# How to make a timer that shows how much time has passed in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, timer, swiftui, format

I am trying to add a timer to the top of my view that shows how long that view has been open.

So far this is what I have:

```
@State var isTimerRunning = false
@State private var startTime =  Date()
@State private var timerString = "0:0"
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

Text(self.timerString)
    .font(Font.system(.largeTitle, design: .monospaced))
    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
        if self.isTimerRunning {
            timerString = String(format: "%.2f", (Date().timeIntervalSince( self.startTime)))
            }
        }
     .onAppear() {
         if !isTimerRunning {
             timerString = "0:0"
             startTime = Date()
         }
         isTimerRunning.toggle()
     }
```

However it shows milliseconds and seconds in the form "1.32434234234234" when I want it to display seconds and minutes in the form "12:43".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an extension of TimeInterval for this. You can customize the string pretty well by changing the `formatter.unitsStyle` (`.positional` will show 00:00:00, while `.abbreviated` will show 0h 0m 0s) and the `formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior` variables.

Credits for the [extension found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999022/how-to-format-time-intervals-for-user-display-social-network-like-in-swift).

```
extension TimeInterval {
    func format(using units: NSCalendar.Unit) -> String {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = units
        formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
        return formatter.string(from: self) ?? ""
    }
}

struct TimerPlayground: View {
    @State var isTimerRunning = false
    @State private var startTime =  Date()
    @State var interval = TimeInterval()
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(interval.format(using: [.hour, .minute, .second]))
            .font(Font.system(.largeTitle, design: .monospaced))
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                if self.isTimerRunning {
                    interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
                }
            }
             .onAppear() {
                 if !isTimerRunning {
                     startTime = Date()
                 }
                 isTimerRunning.toggle()
             }
    }
}

struct TimerPlayground_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimerPlayground()
    }
}
```

Inline with @Duncan C's comment, here's an updated version which creates the formatter only once (locally) for better performance.

```
struct TimerPlayground: View {
    @State var isTimerRunning = false
    @State private var startTime =  Date()
    @State var interval = TimeInterval()
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @State var formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(formatter.string(from: interval) ?? "")
            .font(Font.system(.largeTitle, design: .monospaced))
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                if self.isTimerRunning {
                    interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
                }
            }
             .onAppear() {
                 if !isTimerRunning {
                     startTime = Date()
                 }
                 isTimerRunning.toggle()
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to write an answer suggesting using a `DateComponentsFormatter`. One nit, though: The extension creates a new `DateComponentsFormatter` every time it's called. If you're going to do this over and over it's better to pull out the formatter into a lazy var that belongs to the containing class/struct.

Comment: @DuncanC Great point. I updated the answer, but ran into "Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable" when trying to make it a lazy var. If you have a better solution, feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dateComponents` to get the difference between start time and the current time.

```
extension Date {
    func passedTime(from date: Date) -> String {
        let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute, .second], from: date, to: self)
        
        let strMin = String(format: "%02d", difference.minute ?? 00)
        let strSec = String(format: "%02d", difference.second ?? 00)
        
        return "\(strMin):\(strSec)"
    }
}
```

And in view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isTimerRunning = false
    @State private var startTime =  Date()
    @State private var timerString = "00:00"
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.timerString)
            .font(Font.system(.largeTitle, design: .monospaced))
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                if self.isTimerRunning {
                    timerString = Date().passedTime(from: startTime)
                }
            }
            .onAppear() {
                if !isTimerRunning {
                    timerString = "0:0"
                    startTime = Date()
                }
                isTimerRunning.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```